# React 18 SSR chunk preload (like in @loadable)

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-suspense

[Using ChunkExtractor from @loadable/server](https://loadable-components.com/docs/server-side-rendering/#3-setup-chunkextractor-server-side), we can include links in the body of the page to preload the necessary chunks during SSR.

This speeds up hydration by having these scripts loaded at the same time as the main chunk just after the HTML document.

How can I do the same with React 18 SSR + Lazy/Suspense without @loadable?

renderToPipeableStream`s [onAllReady](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/14c2be8dac2d5482fda8a0906a31d239df8551fc/packages/react-dom/src/server/ReactDOMFizzServerNode.js#L36-L46) callback has no arguments.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?